# How to create SVG responsive polygon with points given in vw/vh units?

Tags: html, css, svg

Let's say I have a triangle like in the example below. But the points are in pixels. I'm trying to use this triangle as a background element. Is it possible to pass those points in vw/vh units?

```html
<svg >
    <polygon className='svg1' points="50,0 100,100 100,0"  />
</svg>
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want a triangle background simply consider gradient like below:

```css
body {
  margin:0;
  height:100vh;
  background:linear-gradient(to top right,transparent 49.5%,#000 50%);
}
```

Or with SVG like that:

```css
body {
  background:url('data:image/svg+xml;utf8,<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" version="1.1" viewBox="0 0 100 100" preserveAspectRatio="none" ><polygon points="0,0 100,100 100,0"  /></svg>') 0 0/100% 100%;
  margin:0;
  height:100vh;
}
```

Comment: Did this answer solve your problem @user11569827 ? If it did accept this answer.